# How to find intersection of two sets of 2D tensors (points on a 2D plane) in Pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have two lists of Pytorch 2D tensors, which are points on a plane:

```
ListA = tensor([ [1.0,2.0], [1.0,3.0], [4.0,8.0] ], device='cuda:0')
ListB = tensor([ [5.0,7.0], [1.0,2.0], [4.0,8.0] ], device='cuda:0')
```

How to compute ?

```
Desired output = tensor([ [1.0,2.0] ,  [4.0,8.0] ], device='cuda:0')
```

I would like to find the ***Intersection*** between two lists `ListA` and `ListB`.

Note : Computation should be carried out only on CUDA.

Comment: Shall the desired output be a 2D as well or you're OK with a 1D?

Comment: Desired output should be 2D points and very fast runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way in PyTorch to accomplish this (i.e., through a function). However, a workaround can be.

[Flatten](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html)ing both tensors:

```
combined = torch.cat((ListA.view(-1), ListB.view(-1)))
combined
Out[52]: tensor([1., 2., 1., 3., 4., 8., 5., 7., 1., 2., 4., 8.], device='cuda:0')
```

Finding [unique](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unique.html?highlight=torch%20unique#torch.unique) elements:

```
unique, counts = combined.unique(return_counts=True)
intersection = unique[counts > 1].reshape(-1, ListA.shape[1])
intersection
Out[55]: 
tensor([[1., 2.],
        [4., 8.]], device='cuda:0')
```

**Benchmarks**:

```
def find_intersection_two_tensors(A: tensor, B:tensor):
       combined = torch.cat((A.view(-1), B.view(-1)))
       unique, counts = combined.unique(return_counts=True)
       return unique[counts > 1].reshape(-1, A.shape[1])
```

Timing it

```
%timeit find_intersection_two_tensors(ListA, ListB)
207 µs ± 2.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

If you are ok with moving to CPU, numpy could be a better solution in regards to performance:

```
def find_intersection_two_ndarray(AGPU: tensor, BGPU: tensor):
      A = AGPU.view(-1).cpu().numpy()
      B = BGPU.view(-1).cpu().numpy()
      C = np.intersect1d(A, B)
      return torch.from_numpy(C).cuda('cuda:0')
```

Timing it

```
%timeit find_intersection_two_ndarray(ListA, ListB)
85.4 µs ± 1.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I also edited the numpy snippet and enhanced it a little bit.